# Cant detect when a player joins a world

Tags: java-8, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So im trying to make this mod give you 2 apples (for testing purposes) but I cant seem to get it to work :/ (no errors nothing the mod does not output anything) here's my code (1.8.9 Forge BTW):

```
    @SubscribeEvent
public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
{
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(EventHandler.class);
}
@SubscribeEvent
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerLoggedInEvent event)
{
    event.player.inventory.addItemStackToInventory(new ItemStack(Items.apple, 2));
    event.player.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("test"));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have log ? Crash error or something ? What do you mean with "doesn't work" ?

Comment: When I join a single player world it does *nothing* no output from the mod, no errors nothing it just does nothin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minecraft uses two different event systems for some reason. `init` is supposed to be `@EventHandler`, not `@SubscribeEvent`. `onPlayerJoin` is correct though. (Add `import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;` if you don't already have it.)

Also, if `onPlayerJoin` is in your `MainGuts` class, then you need to do either `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(MainGuts.class);` or `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);` (try both; I forget which is correct all the way back in 1.8.9), not `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(EventHandler.class);`.

Comment: hmmm I did what you said but still nothing :/ here's all of the code:
https://pastebin.com/eNUwSmcx

Comment: @CodingWiz Okay, I saw another mistake in there and added its fix to my answer. Btw, you should edit your question to include all of that code.

Comment: got rid of the static and the "this" one worked.